# Creating a sufficient database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Please look at the attachment while reading this. Thanks! It's created purely for visual input

I'm currently creating a database for a project, and I bumped into this issue:

I want to use something that I've called Doctype to distinguish the data_fields for the document. For example, when a contract is uploaded I want to use a specific table with its unique columns. like table Data_field_1. But if the Doctype is a **receipt** I want it to use table Data_field_2 where the fields are customized.

I am aware that there would be issues doing it this way. Therefore my question is: is there a possible solution to this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are right that doesn't make sense, because they can all be in one table and use the id of doctype to differentiate, if you want them separated, you make a VIEW or a partition

Comment: @nbk What would you do? Separate them or keep them in one table. The problem with putting them in one table is that for a contract I would want different rows, like who signed, what date, and so on. While with a receipt I wouldn't need the row for who signed, instead I would need other rows like seller. Sorry for the twisted explanation

Comment: as i wrote keep them in one table, as long you don't have restrictions by security or SOPs.  you can add to the table as many columns a you need to represent all information, try to normalize, so that the size is not to big

Comment: Sounds like you want inheritance. There are around four different implementation strategies forit: one is to put everything on a single table. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @TheImpaler I added a second picture. Obviously there would be more columns, but that's a start. Thank you! I see the problem with connecting the doctype to the data field, it doesn't work in my example.

Comment: A practical example: I'm to add documentation. I enter the values for name, datatype, (..), doctype. Lets say it's a contract => I enter the value 1 in doctype. What I want essentially, that is missing is the "connection" between documentation and the data_fields. Thanks

Comment: @VorteXx3 That's a typical example of "table inheritance". That means for each row in `DocType` there will be one row in either `Data_Field1`, `Data_Field2`, etc. These secondary tables may be inclusive, but most of the times they are mutually exclusive. If that's the case you'll need to add an extra column to the main table `DocType` to ensure the database never insert in more than one "child table" for the same DocType.

Comment: @TheImpaler I see, thank you! So if I understood this right; the column I add to the main table Doctype works like an 'id' that ensures the correct linking? What would be a suitable name for it, and what value should I give it? is it a FK for the data_fields? Or is it a FK that relates back to the Documentation table? Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you misunderstood, the doctype table is filled with data beforehand. Like id=1 will belong to name=contract, id=2  receipt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement "Table Inheritance". There are around four different strategies to do it. I'll show the most common one, that I personally think it's the most flexible and safe one.

I'll assume your *child tables* are mutually exclusive, since this is the most common case. For example, you can do:

```
create table Documentation (
  id int primary key not null,
  title varchar(100)
);

create table DocType ( -- this is the parent table
  id int not null,
  type char(1) not null check (type in ('c', 'r', 's', 'o')),
  data_field int,
  name varchar(50),
  primary key (id, type),
  foreign key (data_field) references Documentation (id)
);

create table Contract ( -- this is a child table "Contract"
  id int not null,
  type char(1) not null check (type = 'c'),
  start_date date,
  end_date date,
  primary key (id, type),
  foreign key (id, type) references DocType (id, type)
);

create table Receipt ( -- this is a child table "Receipt"
  id int not null,
  type char(1) not null check (type = 'r'),
  buyer varchar(20),
  seller varchar(20),
  primary key (id, type),
  foreign key (id, type) references DocType (id, type)
);
```

Then, you can try inserting some data:

```
insert into Documentation (id, title)
  values (123, 'First Document');

insert into DocType (id, type, data_field, name)
  values (1001, 'c', 123, 'Contract #1');  

insert into Contract (id, type, start_date, end_date)
  values (1001, 'c', '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31');
```

Finally, I you try to insert a "receipt" for the same DocType it won't work (as expected), since we are enforced exclusivity:

```
insert into Receipt (id, type, buyer, seller) 
  values (1001, 'r', 'buyer1', 'seller2');
```

> Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`Receipt`, CONSTRAINT `Receipt_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `type`) REFERENCES `DocType` (`id`, `type`))

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHd8MLGEiQSBSSCRwUrpV/0).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look more into table inheritance, seems like a good solution.